# Backing up win 7 files to unrecognized external hd

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive

[image]

I have an win7 laptop that I'd like to backup. I have an old wd 500 gb external usb hdd. I tried to use the win7 backup program (typing 'backup' at cmd line), but the edd is not recognized for backup  even though I can see it is recognized as a device. (In the screenshot you can see it recognized as 'DISK 1' with 3 partitions). What do I need to do to cause win7 to recognize it for backup? should I be using another program?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a drive letter to the large partition on your backup drive before Windows can see it.  You'll have that problem no matter which backup software you use.

Right-click the large 465 GB partition there in disk management and choose "Change Drive Letter and Paths" from the drop-down, then click Add... on the window that appears.  Assign it any drive letter you want from the drop-down (avoid A or B), after which Windows should mount the drive, and you'll be good to go.

If Windows keeps failing to mount the drive in the future when you plug it in, you can also try opening a command window, typing 'diskpart', then typing 'automount enable' at the prompt.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help. It didn't work exactly that way for me, as this option was not allowed. I ended up deleting the partition, and creating a simple ntfs partition. I was then able to assign a drive letter.